# Cucumber Failed to Load 'yml' Programming Language for File

Tags: cucumber, yaml, watir-webdriver, rubymine

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to run a Cucumber scenario using watir-webdriver step definitions:

```
Failed to load 'yml' programming language for file .../features/support/config.yml:
cannot load such file -- cucumber/yml_support/yml_language
* .../features/support/config.yml [NOT SUPPORTED]
* .../features/support/lib/configuration.rb
```

The contents of my config.yml file are as follows:

```
:browser: :chrome
:url: http://example.com
```

The above is clearly valid yaml.

I don't understand why Cucumber is saying this isn't supported. Any thoughts??

Additionally - It seems as though this may be a RubyMine issue, since I don't see this error when I run the cucumber feature through Terminal.

Comment: I recently started seeing this when I switched to RubyMine 5.0. Though it's a non-fatal error for the script.

Answer (score 0):

I already faced this issue. But I modified the yaml file keys and values. Now it's working fine.

Could you try the below contents in your yaml file.

> browser: chrome
>
> url: "http://example.com"

Answer (score 0):

try in this manner

```
browser: chrome
url: http://example.com
```

and for browser you will need to convert the string into symbol like this

```
browser.to_sym
```

Answer (score 0):

You might see this error in console logs while running in verbose mode.

Run it in non verbose mode.